# Get managedObject by objectID

Tags: ios, swift, nsmanagedobject

I'm trying to update `managedObject`. I've read that every `managedObject` has property `objectID`, and I've created a function for updating objects. I'm trying to get object by `objectID` using predicate,

but i get an error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'keypath objectID not found in
>   entity '

It seems like I don't have access to this property ?

Below is a code of my function.

```
func updateNote(noteToUpdate: NoteMO) {
    let managedContext = CoreDataManager.sharedManager.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<NoteMO> = NoteMO.fetchRequest()
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "objectID = %@", "\(noteToUpdate.objectID)")

    do{
        let foundedObject = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
        let objectUpdate = foundedObject[0] as! NoteMO
        objectUpdate.setValue(noteToUpdate.name, forKey: "name")
        objectUpdate.setValue(noteToUpdate.text, forKey: "text")
        do {
            try managedContext.save()
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Comment: You want [existingObject(with:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontext/1506686-existingobject)

Comment: I can try it, looks like it's exactly what I need

Comment: it isn't clear why you are trying to fetch the object that you already have - `noteToUpdate` is the object you want.

Comment: I'm changing its properties and send to previous viewController by delegate, and in that place i should fetch it and update its properties. I've read many articles and it seems to be impossible to update managedObject by objectID

Comment: But you don't need to fetch the managed object; you already have it.  `noteToUpdate` *is* the `NoteMO` object you would get back from the fetch. It's attributes already have the new values. Your `setValue` calls are effectively saying `noteToUpdate.name = noteToUpdate.name`. All you need to do is save the context to commit the changes that have already been made to the managed object

Comment: Really, it works. I've thought that I have to fetch it if I want to update.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189109/discussion-between-paulw11-and-michal-lewczuk).